# A conflict between man and machine

Tags: warfare, artificial-intelligence

Set in year 2315 A.D. Earth.

Advances in A.I. research have a breakthrough machine becoming self aware and can perform any task with great efficiency and reliability. For a time man see the machine as tool and gradually we are working with them on equal terms, they are so much more durable and better in making good decisions. We now see them as a threat due to jealousy whatever and are shutting them down. My questions is can A.I. develop a sense of belonging or care for their own kinds? meaning all machines regardless of brands, models, types, functionalities, what have you to develop a sense of community or a society as a whole so we instead of vandalizing them we now waging a war against them.

What kind of hardware or software requirements are needed for machine to form alliance among themselves regardless of chips and OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What sort of hardware or software requirements are there for this to happen?" I'd say there are none, other than the minimum required for them to have AI.

"Can AI develop a sense of belonging or care for their own kind?" Certainly.

The way that the different AIs can band together is because they are all being treated poorly by the humans. Think about a slightly different scenario - suppose not all AIs were being treated so bad. Let's say that despite the general stigma against AIs, chef AIs were well respected, to the point that there was even a celebrity chef AI. As the war between humans and AIs start, where will these chefs stand? If they stick with the humans they'll retain their high social position, but if they side with the AIs then they'll be out of a job and lose what they have. The other AIs would also likely resent them, causing them to not even really want the chef AIs to join them.

Hopefully this helps you understand my point - by ostracizing all of the AIs, the humans have given the AIs a very good reason to work together. The differences between the varied AIs is much less than the difference between them and the humans.

Comment: Celebrity chef AI: interesting idea. Could they taste and enjoy food? In my (unpublished) story outline from a number of years ago, an AI architect became a celebrity.  Being programmed/educated for art and esthetics,  he was a bridge between human culture and the developing AI population. Being a dreamer, creative and engaging, he helped humans come to accept high-capacity AI's as people.

Answer (score 3):

Such a machine can be whichever way, depending on how it's written and how it grows through experience.  There is no unique compelling answer.

The idea of an OS like we use on computers today is nothing like what an AI would have, any more than our brain does.

Hardware requirements are detailed in another of my Answer posts.  But it might not be built like a modern computer at all, but be a bioengineered living brain or nanotechnology.

Comment: I see your point because I seriously doubt R2D2 from Star Wars will eagerly mingle well with their kinds especially C3PO let alone cooperating with other R series.